# 'fitBounds' react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to show multiple locations with zoom but i get error.

any help please or how make a context leflet in

thanks

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState, createRef } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, FeatureGroup } from 'react-leaflet';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { Button, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
const M = ({ data, type }) => {

   
    const maRef = createRef();
    const groupRef = createRef();
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        
        const map = maRef.current.leafletElement;
        const group = groupRef.current.leafletElement;
        map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
    
      }
      
    
      
     
   return (
    <>
    <Button onClick={handleClick} >Zoom</Button>
       <MapContainer  ref={maRef} center={[48.91446, 3.0318123]} zoom={8} scrollWheelZoom={true} className={"map"}>
           <TileLayer
               attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
               url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
           />
           <FeatureGroup ref={groupRef}>
       {data?.map((f,i) =>       
          <Marker key={i} position={[f.latitude,f.longitude]}>
          <Popup>
           <Typography><span style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Type:</span> {type[i]}</Typography>    
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
        
       )}
       </FeatureGroup>          
       </MapContainer>
       </>
   );
};
```

package.json
i try to change versions but it's the same error(Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fitBounds')

```
 "leaflet": "^1.9.1",
"leaflet-routing-machine": "^3.2.12",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-leaflet": "^4.1.0",
```